# How to show fresh bootstrap modal data when using Vue.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I have a table of records about our clients (i.e. customers).  When the user clicks through them, it loads a bootstrap modal that includes the customer's details in a form.  The user may then edit and submit the form.

The table is output by a Vue component, and the modal is a child Vue component.  When the user clicks on the first record, it populates the modal and shows it, which is fine.  The problem is that when the user closes the modal and clicks on another record, the modal opens with the data from the first record.

I have found a way around this, as you can see in the code below, but it relies on trapping the bootstrap 'show modal' event.  Is there a cleaner way to do it with Vue?  Something that resets the data in the child component when a record is selected in the parent component?

```
    export default {
    props : [
        'client_id',
        'name',
        'job_code',
        'is_default'
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            localJobCode : '',
            localIsDefault : ''
        }
    },
    methods : {
        doSave() {
             // ....
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        let self = this;
        $(this.$refs.EditClientModal).on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            self.localJobCode = self.job_code;
            self.localIsDefault = self.is_default;
        });
    }
}
```

In the template I the modal element has a ref tag, as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-client-modal" tabindex="-1" ref="EditClientModal">
```

As you can see, I am creating a local copy of the props (because obviously I don't want to mutate the value in the child).  The code in the `mounted()` method is the only way I can see to refresh the data each time the modal is shown.  Am I missing something?

Comment: My idea, for modal component, it just need to focus on model layout/effect, it doesn't care about its content of model hear/body. So use `<slot>` to pass header/body to model, uses `props=@actions` pass `save/cancel` event. Then when user clicks one row of the table, open the model using header/body populated with the content generated based on the row selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap modal component in a div and bind to it a unique key. When the key changes component will be recreate again

```
<div class="modal-wrapper" :key="client_id">
  <div class="modal fade" id="edit-client-modal" tabindex="-1" ref="EditClientModal">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: @KimPrince You can use computed instead of data, in computed, like `computed: { computedJobCode: function () { return this.job_code ? this.job_code : 'defaultValue'}}`